# How to fix the problem of file.exe stop running after one insertion in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float point;
    char grade;
    struct node *next;
    };
struct node *head;
void DataEntry(struct node *);
void GetData(struct node *);
void DataDisp();

void Insert()
{
    struct node *p;
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    DataEntry(p);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=p;

    }
    else
    {

        struct node *q;
        q=head;
        while(q!=NULL)
        {
            q=q->next;
        }
        q->next=p;
        p->next=NULL;

    }


}
void DataEntry(struct node *p)
{
        printf("Enter value of Id employee\n");
        scanf("%d",&p->id);
        printf("Enter name of the person\n");
        scanf("%s",p->name);
        printf("Enter points got by Employee\n");
        scanf("%f",&p->point);
        printf("Enter grade of the person\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&p->grade);
}
void GetData(struct node *q)
{
    printf("The data entered by you is as follows\n");
    printf("Id is %d\n",q->id);
    printf("Name is %s\n",q->name);
    printf("Point is %f\n",q->point);
    printf("Grade is %c\n",q->grade);
}
void DataDisp()
{
    struct node *z;
    z=head;
    if(z==NULL)
    {
        printf("List is Empty\n");
        return;
    }
    while(z!=NULL)
    {
        GetData(z);
        z=z->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Insert();
    DataDisp();
}
```

I have implemented a singly linked list, I insert data in a list using Insert() function and displaying the data using DataDisp() function in DataDisp() function I have used GetData() function which is accessing data from linked list nodes. The problem here is I can do the first insertion and it displays data also using DataDisp() but after that, there is error file.exe stop running. I think there is a segmentation fault; I tried my best to solve the problem but could not run it successfully. Please help.

Comment: `while(q!=NULL) {...}` - what value is `q` guaranteed to have after that loop?

Comment: I think it contains NULL; I tried with while(q->next!=NULL) {...} still the problem is the same.

Comment: with while(q->next!=NULL) works fine for one Inert() and DataDisp() call ;but after  I again call Insert() and DataDisp() function then it directly goes in DataDisp() function and stops working.

Comment: hey,user3121023 thanks bro ..it is working...your previous solution itself solved my problem...

Comment: user3121023,your second comment gave me way to avoid fflush(stdin);..thank you

Comment: This code can't work as in `q->next=p;` `q` will be null, so you get a seg fault. See @Mat's comment.

Comment: while(q->next!=NULL)
        {
            q=q->next;
        }
        q->next=p;    This code worked for me..

Answer (score -1):

ONE MORE THING IS TRY TO PREVENT USE OF "FFLUSH" KEYWORD.THIS IS NOT A PORTABLE WAY OF CLEANING THE INPUT BUFFER, AND MAY NOT WORK WITH ALL COMPILER.